# Changing values that are the same from different nodes

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need to localize values within siblings that are the same. If they are the same I need to alter them.

I think I need to use following-sibling and preceding-sibling and group-by in some way. First group-by the value I am looking for so that I get the one's that are the same in the position after each other. Then using the sibling functions to  find out if they are equal.

Sample:

```
<programs>
    <event>
        <start>2018-11-25T13:55:00</start>
    </event>
    <event>
        <start>2018-11-27T17:00:00</start>
    </event>
    <event>
        <start>2018-11-25T13:55:00</start>
    </event>
    <event>
        <start>2018-11-25T13:55:00</start>
    </event>
</programs>
```

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:for-each select="/programs/event">
                <xsl:variable name="starttime" select="./start"/>
                <startOfProgram><xsl:value-of select="$starttime"/></startOfProgram>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired results:

```
<output>
    <startOfProgram>2018-11-25T13:55:00</startOfProgram>
    <startOfProgram>2018-11-25T13:56:00</startOfProgram>
    <startOfProgram>2018-11-25T13:57:00</startOfProgram>
    <startOfProgram>2018-11-27T17:00:00</startOfProgram>
</output>
```

I know this is a long shot so if anyone could point me in the right direction or help me with one part of the problem I'd be very grateful.

There is lots of other elements in the sample that I have taken out that is also carried though to the output. If it matters I can include a variety of them.

Ps. Note that the value could easily be `2018-11-25T18:30:00`, which would then need to be `2018-11-25T18:30:00` and the consecutive `2018-11-25T18:31:00` if there are more of the same.

Answer (score 0):

The result you have shown looks as if you want to group the values as `xs:dateTime` values and then simply add one minute to each item in the group depending on the position:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="programs">
      <output>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="event/start/xs:dateTime(.)" group-by=".">
              <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                  <startOfProgram>{. + (position() - 1) * xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1M')}</startOfProgram>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </output>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUv/1 and the above is XSLT 3 but for an XSLT 2 processor I think you only need to change the text value template I have used to an `xsl:value-of`:

```
<startOfProgram><xsl:value-of select=". + (position() - 1) * xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1M')"/></startOfProgram>
```

See http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/6qVRKvJ